# php How Boolean Algebra works?

Tags: php, boolean, algebra

I want to know how Boolean Algebra works

and why this happened ??

```
echo 1*1+0*0;
echo "\n";

$part = 1*1+0;
echo $part*0;
echo "\n";
```

output is :

1

0

and if I have an array like this

```
$mx[] = array("",1);
$mx[] = array("*",1);
$mx[] = array("+",0);
$mx[] = array("*",0);
```

how I can get the Boolean result ?

I tried this but it will result wrong

```
function ch($p1,$p2,$prv) { 
$ret = null;

    if ($prv == null) {
        $ret = $p2;
    }   

    if ($prv != null) {

      if ($p1 == "*") {

       $ret = $prv*$p2;

      } 

      if ($p1 == "+") {

       $ret = $prv+$p2;

      } 


  }     
    return $ret;    
}

$prvx = null;

$mx[] = array("",1);
$mx[] = array("*",1);
$mx[] = array("+",0);
$mx[] = array("*",0);

foreach ($mx as $hit) { 
    $prvx = ch($hit[0],$hit[1],$prvx);
}
echo $prvx;
```

Comment: The first question isn't about Boolean: it is simple arithmetic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Note that tagging a question with multiple languages is generally a bad idea, especially when, as here, your question is really only about one of the languages.  You will easily incur the wrath of those who are interested in language tags that are not relevant to the question.  Stick with one language in general.

Comment: Nothing in here is about boolean algebra. `1` and `0` are ordinary numbers, you're just doing grade school arithmetic.

Comment: The second example made me smile: `foreach ($mx as $hit)`

Comment: @WeatherVane why smile ?

Comment: Sorry it was off-topic.

Comment: @beginner cause it reads like `$hitt`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
echo 1*1+0*0;
```

PHP makes use of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) to decide how to group the operations. `*` has higher precedence than `+`, so it's treated as:

```
echo (1*1) + (0*0);
```

which simplifies to:

```
echo 1 + 0;
```

which further simplifies to:

```
echo 1;
```

But when you do your loop that calls `ch`, you don't do any grouping based on the operators, you simply execute each operation in the order that it appears in the `$mx` array. So your operations are equivalent to:

```
echo ((1 * 1) + 0) * 0;
```

which simplifies to:

```
echo (1 + 0) * 0;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
echo 1 * 0;
```

which is:

```
echo 0;
```